React native swiper auto scrolls when swipped
I have a react native swiper component that auto scrolls when I swipe, which results in two  images showing together, but it doesn't do this if I remove  onindexchanged()
the issue
what I want when I swipe
The code
    <Swiper
          index={0}
          loop={false}
          autoplay={false}
          onIndexChanged={(index) => {
          setCurrentIndex(index)
          }}
          showsPagination={false}
          loadMinimal
          loadMinimalSize={1}
          horizontal={false}
        >
          {[{ id: "cover", image: image }, ...images]
            .filter((item) => item.image)
            .map((item, index) => (
              <Manga
                key={item.id}
                coverImage={item.image}
                img={item.image}
                index={index}
                blurStatus={blurStatus}
                overlayVisible={overlayVisible}
                commentsForImages={commentsForImages}
                refRBSheet={refRBSheet}
              />
            ))}
        </Swiper>

this causes the issue
  onIndexChanged={(index) => {
            setCurrentIndex(index);
          }}

this doesn't
    onIndexChanged={(index) => {
            console.log(index)
          }}


By using lodash, you can silence the instantaneous incoming data a little bit.
ex:
const handleIndexChanged = useCallback(
  debounce((index) => {
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  }, 100), 
  []
);


Thank you, I tried lodash , it didn't work
